# How can I change parameterized type in collection?

Tags: java, rest, collections, stream

I would like to use collection in one method in my `UserServiceImpl` to return the list of all users which will be parameterized by `UserDTO`.
I have the following method:

```
@Override
public List<UserEntity> getUsers() {
    var usersList = userRepository.findAll();
    return usersList;
}
```

But I want to change it to `public List<UserDTO> getUsers()...` I have `map` method from entity to dto and vice versa:

```
public UserDTO mapToUserDTO(UserEntity userEntity) {
    var userDto = new UserDTO();
    var rolesEntity = userEntity.getRoles().stream()
            .map(RoleEntity::getId)
            .map(String::valueOf)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    userDto.setId(userEntity.getId());
    userDto.setUsername(userEntity.getUsername());
    userDto.setName(userEntity.getName());
    userDto.setSurname(userEntity.getSurname());
    userDto.setEmail(userEntity.getEmail());
    userDto.setAge(userEntity.getAge());
    userDto.setRoles(rolesEntity);
    return userDto;
}
```

But in this case it cannot be applied.
Could you help me out please - how can I change parametrized type from `UserEntity` to `UserDTO` in my method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a stream over the list of user entities, transform each entity into a DTO via `map()` operation and the method you've shared and collect the result into a list.

```
public List<UserDTO> getUsers() {
    
    return userRepository.findAll().stream()
        .map(this::mapToUserDTO)       // or ClassName::mapToUserDTO
        .collect(Collectors.toList()); // or .toList() for Java 16+
}
```